# How to randomly click an element in the list (Android)using selenium+Appium?

Tags: java, android, appium

Below code throws an array illegal out of bound exception

```
java.util.List <MobileElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='com.bankappointmentschedulingmobile:id/bankType'][@index=0]"));
System.out.println(ele.size());
Random rnd = new Random();
int rndInt = rnd.nextInt(ele.size());
((org.openqa.selenium.WebElement) ele.get(rndInt)).click();
```

Elements in the UI automator:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use XPath in above case because you have element ID. Also, you are adding a check for index=0, it means it will check elements only with index 0. In the below example, I am finding elements using ID = "bankType" and printing its size. While generating random number I have subtracted "1" because the index will start from 0.

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.id("bankType"));
System.out.println("Total elements : " + elementList.size());

Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.nextInt(elementList.size()-1); // -1 because index will start from 0

elementList.get(index).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Used this approach with appium using ruby, but this one should be good if you have fewer elements and also since, both of my elements had different xpath's.

```
 And(/^I select the choice in cooking style$/) do
  style = 
['//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]/UIAStaticText[1]]' , '//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[2]/UIAStaticText[1]']
  cookingstyle = style.sample
  find_element(xpath: cookingstyle).click
  puts cookingstyle

end
```